# Insert numbers in base R heatmap's cells

Tags: r, heatmap

I am building a simple heatmap in base R.
This is my matrix:

```
stleft = matrix( 
     c(0,5,5,2,6,8,4,6,9), 
     nrow=3, 
     ncol=3) 
colnames(stleft) <- c("Narrow","Wide", "Wider")
rownames(stleft) <- c("Person", "Object","Bare")
stleft
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
> stleft
       Narrow Wide Wider
Person      0    2     4
Object      5    6     6
Bare        5    8     9
```

To build the heat map I simply run:

```
par(oma=c(3, 0, 0, 3))
col <- rev(heat.colors(999))
heatmap(stleft, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none")
```

[image]

Do you know how I can insert the matrix's numbers in the heat map's cells?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789549/display-a-matrix-including-the-values-as-a-heatmap

Comment: @bbiasi, thank you! that worked great